# how to speed retrieving data from big table data when select from it?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sqltransaction

Problem

I have table have 20 columns when make select data from new SQL query computer hangs ?

what suggestion to make quickly read data from this table and make performance good ?

What I Try

==========

```
select * from table where 1=1 
take 45 minutes
```

after minimize column number as

```
select column 1,column 2,column 3 from table
```

also hangs but take less time as 42 minutes .

when make select data from tables not other programs open only SQL server opened new query.

table have 1 million records .

Computer Capability

==============

i work on SQL server 2012.

select data from this table hangs computer although my computer capability not bad

ram 8 GIGA and processor core I 5 .

I try same Backup of data on another computer it take too much time as above ?

==============

if possible what suggestions to select data quickly from table and best performance ?

Comment: first question would be: why are you selecting everything?

Comment: thank you for reply i make select to every thing because i have reports work with totals mustdisplay to customers daily

Comment: one million record for only one customer only so that i ask

Comment: question makes no sense. Noone displays millions of records daily. If you want Totals, calculate them in SQL....

Comment: Can you post the schema for your table? If you have `NVarChar( Max )` columns and others of similar size it will impact performance.

Answer (score -2):

If data is inserting/updating in this tables at the time of select query you may face deadlock issues.

Try with(nolock) and check if table has proper indexes.

```
select * from table with(nolock) where 1=1
```

Rebuild the indexes.

Comment: "Try with(nolock)" -  No, don't do that. Very poor advice.